# localstorage values get reset after refreshing page and inserting new values

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So, I'm sucessfully saving the values I want to localstorage, but everytime I hit refresh, and insert a new array, these values are cleared and only the new array stays. How do I make it so all the values are saved permanently? Thanks!

```
let users = []
let logged = false;
let indexUtilizador = 0;

window.onload = function () {

class User {
    constructor(user, pass, email, tipouser,lastId) { 
        this.user = user
        this.pass = pass
        this.email = email
        this.tipouser = tipouser  ou docente    
        this._id = User.getLastId() + 1
    }
}


let registerUser = document.getElementById('newAccount')

document.getElementById("register").onclick = function() {
    console.log("Ola")
    let user = document.getElementById('user').value
    let pass = document.getElementById('pass').value
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value
    let usertype = document.getElementById('usertype').value

    let newUser = new User(user, pass, email, usertype)

    users.push(newUser)

    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users))

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see the bit where you are retrieving the current users from storage?

Comment: because you are using same key "users" in each time you are saving the data. This will override the existing users array with new one. If you need to keep all the data, use a dynamic key as such as "users_1", "users_2" .. etc.
See my answer below.

Comment: first line: `let users = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("users") );` (but it might fail horribly if there is no such item D:  heck if I know.)

Answer (score 1):

Use something similar to insert data.

```
localStorage.setItem("users_"+new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(users))
```

This will save users as different records.

Answer (score 1):

In following line of your code, you are using the key "user" to store data into localStorage. Due to storing new data again with same key will overwrite the existing data.

```
localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users))
```

Try using different keys for Everytime you storing data into localStorage.

For example you can count the number of users and append that count with your key to store data.
Following is the possible way.

```
var count = getCount(); 
//get count will be your function to get the count of users 
localStorage.setItem("users" + count, JSON.stringify(users))
```

Answer (score 0):

Test to see if exists before writing.

```
let user =  localStorage.getItem("users");
if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users))

  //...
}
```